# "render :partial" can't find files when called on its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a **rails 2.2.2** app with the following odd problem.

There's a `.js.rjs` file, which is rendered to produce javascript as the response to a .js format query.

If i do this, it works fine:

```
page.replace_html "search-results-resources-paginated", :partial => "search/discover_results"
```

Ie, it renders out the `app/views/search/_discover_results.html.erb` partial (which in turn calls other partials).  That's all working fine.

However, I want to break this down into a couple of steps, where i render the partial into a text string, and then use that string in the javascript (i just want to do this for a bit of extra debugging).

I'm trying to do this like so:

```
text = render(:partial => "search/discover_results")
page.replace_html "search-results-resources-paginated", :text => text
```

this is now starting to complain about not being able to find the partial:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (Missing template search/_discover_results.erb in view path 
  /app/views:
  <project folder>/app/views/community:
  <project folder>/vendor/plugins/savage_beast/app/views:
  <project folder>/vendor/plugins/exception_notification/app/views:
  <project folder>/vendor/plugins/query_reviewer/lib/query_reviewer/lib/query_reviewer/views:
) on line #49 of app/views/search/discover.js.rjs:
```

(i've formatted the above a little, for clarity)

If i tell render the actual file extension, like so:

```
text = render(:partial => "search/discover_results.html.erb")
```

then it finds that first partial, but i get the same problem with other partials this it references.  It's like `render` doesn't know that it's supposed to be looking for `html.erb` files, rather than just `.erb` files.

Is there an extra option i need to pass to `render` to make this work?

thanks, Max

Comment: I don't suppose renaming the 'text' variable to something else would alter the result?

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN fraid not. `text` isn't a ruby keyword, anyway.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't you have to use `render_to_string` if you wanted to render to a text string?

Comment: @JanBussieck `render_to_string` is only available in the controller, for me: i can't use it inside the js.rjs file.